# Tomcat embedded in Eclipse doesn't work when launched from Eclipse. What have I done wrong?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Newly installed Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 32 bit.  New workspace.

Open servers view, See "No servers are available.  Click this link to create a new server."

Click the link.

Choose Apache Tomcat 7.0

It offers to install apache-tomcat-7.0.47. I accept this

I accept the license terms

It asks for an installation directory I specify C:\apps\apache-tomcat-7.0.  This directory did not exist previously.

Everything looks fine.

I start the server in eclipse.  Console is clean of errors.

```
...
Jun 11, 2015 8:50:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 11, 2015 8:50:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 11, 2015 8:50:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 558 ms
```

I open a web browser window (or do same from external browser).

I type the url http://localhost:8080

Get 404 error page

I stop server in eclipse.

In DOS window I

```
cd C:\apps\apache-tomcat-7.0\bin
startup
```

Again it starts cleanly.

Now, from either the internal eclipse browser or an external one, http://localhost:8080 shows the Tomcat welcome page.

Two differences I note:
  Have I done
1) Eclipse launch is using jdk 1.7, which I have set as default, while system is using jdk 1.8.  Switching JREs makes no difference however.

2) the log entries are as above except I see "http-apr-8080" and "ajp-apr-8080" when running standalone instead of "http-bio-8080" and "ajp-bio-8080" when I run from within Eclipse.

Can someone tell me what is going on?  Have I done something wrong?

UPDATE:  I tried adding a JBoss server to the Workspace.  This works without issue.  Everything works out of the box.  Deployed apps work, the default page works (http://localhost:8080), etc.  So it would seem that there are some issues with the Eclipse/Tomcat tooling.

Comment: To sum it up -> **launching from Eclipse works just fine**, only the default webapp (*It works!*) is not included. Eclipse changes `catalina.home` and webapps directory. To run your application from Eclipse you need to add it via `Server > Add and Remove...` context menu.

Comment: @PavelHoral - This sounds reasonable - yet when I do Add/Remove it tells me "there are no resources that can be added or removed from the server".  If I whip up some webapp in Eclipse, then Add/Remove opens but I still don't know how to make it include the default ROOT webapp.  And if I add this whipped up web app, I can't access it no matter how I start it.  It seems as though the Eclipse installation is detached somehow from the Tomcat server it installed.

Comment: Projects need to have the *Dynamic Web Module* facet to be able to deploy onto the server (that is a different question already answered here on SO).  Why do you want to include the default ROOT web application? It's just *hello world* to make sure your server is installed and running properly.

Comment: exactly, just a simple diagnostic

Comment: I don't understand your intentions. You can see your server is running by getting 404 error page.

Comment: Nothing I deploy within Eclipse is working, so I wanted to diagnose the simplest possible thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80290/discussion-between-pavel-horal-and-steve-cohen).

Comment: firewall won't allow it.